# Window messages in windows application with no window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application that I want to run in the background with no visible windows or consoles. To accomplish this, I create a windows application but I do not create a window. The application needs to do some cleanup when requested to close (i.e. when the user logs off). How can I determine when to close? Can I simply create a message loop which handles the WM_CLOSE message? But then I have no WndProc to handle the WM_CLOSE message.

Comment: So you don't really have a Windows application but a program that runs in a background, and you want to know that it is being killed by user's request to log off, right?

Comment: Create a window as usual but hide it with EnableWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an application that runs in the background, create a service. A service can respond to the [`ServiceMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls.

If you insist on creting a front end application, there are basically no legit reasons for applications to try to hide their main window. You executable image can be either GUI (`IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI`) or console (`IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI`), and you cannot mix them, see [How do I write a program that can be run either as a console or a GUI application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx). If you choose a GUI application then you are expected to create a message pump. You *may* choose to create a hidden window as your 'main' window. You will get [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_ENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this hidden window (which are the messages you're interested in, not `WM_CLOSE`).

On the other hand a console app will have to handle signals, like Andon already showed you.

Choose your poison. I strongly suggest to go the service route, as is the proper avenue for a 'background' application.

Comment: "there are basically no legit reasons for applications to try to hide their main window" is quite a statement to make, and patently false as well. There's many situations where having a user facing window makes no sense. Child processes doing background work. Programs which are interacted with only through the notification bar. Neither of which are strictly services, but still have no window.

Answer (score 6):

Do not bother with creating a dummy window, there is a much easier way to handle shutdown / exit control events in a windowless application. To do this, you use a little known Win API function called: [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler (...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is an example of how to use the [Control Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h> 

// You can fill-in your own behavior, this is just an example handler that
//   covers most of the most common events.
BOOL
ControlHandler (DWORD dwControlEvent) 
{ 
  switch (dwControlEvent) 
  { 
    // User wants to shutdown
    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: 
      return FALSE; 

    // User wants to logoff
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: 
      return FALSE; 

    // Ctrl + C
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
      return TRUE;

    // User wants to exit the "normal" way 
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
      return TRUE;

    // Everything else, just ignore it...
    default:
      return FALSE; 
  } 
} 

int
main (void) 
{ 
  // Set the control handler so the app will be notified upon any special
  //   termination event.
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler ((PHANDLER_ROUTINE) ControlHandler, TRUE); 

  //
  // Main Loop Here ...
  //

  return 0;
}
```

I had to learn about this a couple of years ago because some middle-ware was not properly cleaning up its resources when my console application was terminated with <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. I discovered it by accident when I was looking at the stack trace. It is worth mentioning that this supercedes the standard signal handler for events like <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

By the way, even though it is called a "Console Control Handler," it works perfectly fine in applications that use `WinMain (...)` instead of `main (...)`.

Comment: Yes I had previously been using that, but I don't want anything visible to the user, no console, no window. Even if I hide the console upon starting, it flashes up, which is not acceptable.

Comment: You don't need a console for this to work, but the service approach is definitely more elegant.

Comment: Service cannot satisfy all needs, e.g. has no access to user input or application because of security. So hidden app running under user account is solution.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options:

1. Create a window, but don't set the WS_VISIBLE flag.
2. Create a [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only).

The difference would be that invisible windows receive broadcast messages, while message-only windows do not.