# Can't print in largest line in C

Tags: c, windows, printing

The program is suppose to print out the longest line in all the outputs.But the program is acting pretty weird. Sometimes it doesn't terminate even when the EOF(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) is triggered and some times it prints blank or weird symbols. I don't why it is not working; can somebody help me fix it please?

```
//START
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define mx 100
int main(void)
{
    int line[mx],lng[mx],c,word,maxim;
    word=1;
    maxim=10;
    int i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
      while((c=getchar())!='\n')
      {
        line[i]=(c=getchar());
        if(((c=getchar())==' ') || ((c=getchar())=='\t'))
           {
            word++;
           }
         i++;
      }
      if(woasdrd>=maxim)
        {
          for(int d=0;d<=99;d++)
         {
            copyline(lng[d],line[d]);
         }
         word=1;
         i=0;
        }
    else
    {
      i=0;
    word=1;
    } 
    }
for(int g;g<=99;g++)
{
    putchar(lng[g]);
}
}
copyline(int to[],int from[])
{
 for(int i=0;i<=99;i++)
  {
        to[i]=from[i];
    }
}
//END
```

Comment: ctr+z not EOF. It is terminate signal.

Comment: _copyline(lng[d],line[d]);_ you are passing two int values and accepting two int arrays. what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The Ctrl + ... signal keys are not always handled the same way you would think in Windows. Console software has a [secondary event handler for those signals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864374/window-messages-in-windows-application-with-no-window/18866072#18866072), that actually supercedes the more traditional signal handling from more "normal" platforms. Nevertheless, `Ctrl + Z` is not one of the handled signals, only Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Break.

Comment: You throw away the first and second characters that you read. You save the third; you read and throw away the fourth character, and if that happens to be a space, you read and throw the fifth character too.  There are a lot of problems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define mx 100

//copy string array from from[] to to[],and both of it is end with '\0'    
void copyline(char to[],char from[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while( from[i] )     
    {
        to[i]=from[i];
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[mx] = { ' ' },lng[mx] = { ' ' }; //line keep the line you just input,lng keep the longest line
    int maxim , c;                             //maxim keep the longest num of longest line
    int i=0;

    maxim=0;

    //get input from stdin ,if EOF then end(Ctrl + C or Ctrl + d is EOF)
    while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        //if you input a Enter then compare it's length with maxim
        if( c == '\n' )
        {
            line[i++] = '\0';          //turn '\n' into '\0',for string end with '\0'

            if( i > maxim )            //compare the line you just input with the longest line,if get longer one,copy it to lng
            {
                maxim = i;
                copyline( lng , line );
                lng[ i ] = '\0';       //for string end with '\0'
            }
            i = 0;                     //if you get a '\n' ,then you should be ready for next input line,so i = 0,and continue for new get
            continue;
        }
        line[i++] = c;              //keep input to line
    }

    //that's output,for string end with '\0',so put it as condition for while loop
    i = 0;
    while( lng[i] )
    {
        printf("%c",lng[i++]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

maybe this is what you want,at first I want to improve your code,but it have much errors,include logic and code,so I rewrite your code.if you have problem with this code,please let me know.

Comment: Sir can you kingly comment the code so it will be easier for me to understand what is happening.And can you also tell me what are my mistakes.

Comment: I have changed my code ,add notes,if you still confused ,please let me know.if you understand the code totaly ,you can find your error,if you have problems please let me know.

Comment: Thankyou sir.It helped and I wrote the code again by myself tell me how it is :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling `getchar()` in too many places. You are removing a character from input every time you call that. Really you should call `c=getchar()` once before the first while loop to read the first character. Remove the rest of the `c=getchar()` and just use `c`. Then at the at the end of the inner while loop right after the `i++;` you should use `c=getchar()` to read the next character.

Comment: The function is just `getchar()` (not `getChar()`).