# What signal/event should my application handle to capture end task & log off?

Tags: c++, winapi, signals

Trying to capture when the user clicks end task from the task manager, and when the user logs off of windows, in order to perform clean-up tasks before closing the application.

After reading [this answer&comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527510/9565106) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18456520/9565106) I got the following conclusions:

1. if my application is a GUI application, I should handle the message `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_ENDSESSION` in my message loop, which will cover both cases (end task and log off).
2. If my application is a console application, I should use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to handle `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` and `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, which will handle both cases.

**Are my conclusions correct?**

If my app doesn't have any window nor a message loop nor a console attached (It's technically a background process that is compiled with the `-mwindows` flag in [MinGW gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html) in order to hide the console window):

- How to capture end task and log off in this case?

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? Also, there is no such thing as *"a GUI app"*. There are threads that have a message queue, and there are threads that do not. Applications usually own a mixture of both threads, and a thread that doesn't have a message queue can be propagated to one that does at any time.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to perform clean-up tasks before my application gets closed by log-off or end task, so I need to capture these 2 events. What do you mean there is no such thing as a GUI app? What do you call an application that has been compiled with `-mwindows` flag on [MinGW gcc?](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html)

Comment: The `-mwindows` flag is a linker option that instructs the linker to produce an image that targets the WINDOWS subsystem (see [/SUBSYSTEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem) for reference). The only difference between a program targeting the CONSOLE subsystem and a program targeting the WINDOWS subsystem is, that the system will allocate a console for the former. There is no other difference. Specifically, a CONSOLE application can display a GUI, and a WINDOWS application can allocate or attach to a console.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh! Didn't know that, thnx. Does that mean I can't use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` because my app doesn't have a console attached? Also, I can't capture `WM_ENDSESSION` unless I put a message loop. Right? How about `signal(SIGINT, handlerFunction)`, will it capture end task and log off without the need for a console or  a message loop?

Comment: @NadAlaba https://stackoverflow.com/a/18866072/65863: "*By the way, even though it is called a "Console Control Handler," [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`] works perfectly fine in applications that use `WinMain (...)` instead of `main (...)`.*" Also, `signal()` doesn't exist on Windows.